# Как во ViewHolder в RecyclerView привязать switchButton к объекту из room БД и кнопку со ссылкой на аудио данного объекта

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter, android-room, viewholder

Коллеги, подскажите пожалуйста новичку как прописать в RecyclerViewAdapter такую связь.

У меня объект Word - это шведское слово, его русский перевод, ссылка на аудио (типа R.raw.s1), и знаение int status (определяет в каком разделе слово появляется, в данном случае оно 200 либо 300).

Вопрос такой:

1. как прописать чтобы кнопка imageViewSound (в itemLayout-e) отсылала к аудиофайлу данного слова;
2. как прописать чтобы switch-кнопка switchStatus меняла в БД room статус слова с 200 на 300 (200 при true, 300 при false)?

   ```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WordHolder holder, int position) {

        Word currentWord = words.get(position);
        holder.textViewSwedish.setText(currentWord.getSwedish());
        holder.textViewRussian.setText(currentWord.getRussian());

        holder.imageViewSound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
    //?????????????????????
        }
        });

        holder.switchStatus.set//??????????;
    }
   ```

Объект так выглядит:

```
@Entity(tableName = "word_table")
public class Word {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;

private String russian;

private String swedish;

private String sound;

private int status;

public Word(String russian, String swedish, String sound, int status) {
    this.russian = russian;
    this.swedish = swedish;
    this.sound = sound;
    this.status = status;
}
```

(там дальше геттеры и сеттеры)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну во-первых сам адаптер уметь работать с БД не должен. Он может, но это плохая практика. Адаптер находится внутри какой-то View (Activity, Fragment и т.п.). При клике на тоггл вы должны сообщить вашей View, о том что пользователь кликнул на тоггл определенного айтема. А уже сама View решит как с этим жить дальше.

Для этого вам нужно создать интерфейс подобно этому:

```
interface OnToggleChangeListener {

    void onToggleChange(currentWord: String, isChecked: Boolean);
}
```

В адаптере:

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> words;
    private OnToggleChangeListener toggleListener;

    MyRecyclerViewAdapter(List<String> items, OnToggleChangeListener clickListener) {
        this.words = words;
        this.toggleListener = toggleListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
         holder.itemView.setOnCheckedChangeListener { view, isChecked -> toggleListener.onToggleChange (words.get(position), isChecked)}
    }

    // другие методы адаптера
}
```

В активити/фрагменте:

```
class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnToggleChangeListener {

    // другие методы активити

    @Override
    void onToggleChange(currentWord: String, isChecked: Boolean) {
        // и вот тут вы делаете все что вам нужно с БД. Лучше конечно если у вас 
        // этим будет заниматсья не активити, а Presenter или View модель или похожая сушность. 
        // Но в целом если вы не работали с архитектурными паттернами, то можете просто здесь работать с БД
    }
}
```

Comment: А где создавать интерфейс?

Comment: Где хотите. Можно внутри адаптера если он только для этого адаптера. Можно рядом отдельным классом. Можно вообще какой-то универсальный создать и положить его к общим файлам. Это уже зависит от вашей иерархии проекта

Comment: Спасибо.  Я всетаки не понял. Сейчас переформулирую новый вопрос с более полной информацией, наверно я мало инфы дал.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1194530/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-switchbutton-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-item-e-%d0%b2-recycleview - вот переделал вопрос

Comment: Не пойму что значит вот эта часть кода? 

MyRecyclerViewAdapter(List<String> items, OnToggleChangeListener clickListener) {
        this.words = words;
        this.toggleListener = toggleListener;
    }

Comment: Это конструктор

Comment: У меня уже есть такие слова "this.words = words" в методе setWords, 
public void setWords(List<Word> words) {
        this.words = words;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
он потом вызывается в основном вью WordList, в том месте где ViewModel, поэтому я не могу написать эту строку получается конфликт

Comment: Это просто пример. Вы можете создать отдельный метод для передачи и списка и листенера, можете передать в конкструкторе. Суть то не в этом.

Comment: В основном Вью такой код:
    wordViewModel.getAllWords().observe(this, new Observer<List<Word>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(List<Word> words) {
                    adapter.setWords(words);
                }
            });
я здесь както могу передать этот switchListener?

Comment: Как угодно. Создайте отдельный сеттер. Только тогда вам придется проверять его постоянно на null.

Comment: { view, isChecked -> toggleListener.onToggleChange (words.get(position), isChecked)} - это разве не Kotlin?

Comment: Это Java 8. Если у вас Java ниже создайте анонимный класс в этом месте

Comment: MyRecyclerViewAdapter(List<String> items, OnToggleChangeListener clickListener) {  -  а здесь наверно вместо clickListener написать toggleListener?